# Is there any evidence that the US interfered in, or contributed to, the events which resulted 2014 Ukranian President's loss of power?

Tags: united-states, ukraine, foreign-interference

In 2014, the then Ukrainian president Yanukovitch absconded the country, and de facto (although not de jure) abdicated power after the protests against him turned violent.

A certain phone call, presumed to be between Assistant Secretary of State Victoria Nuland and the US Ambassador to Ukraine Geoffrey Pyatt, was posted on YouTube.  The content of the call seemed to suggest that the US was influencing the Ukranian Euromaidan Protests.

Is there any other known evidence, or reports, which point to the Ukranian Euromaidan 2014 Protests being US-backed?

Comment: Many people would disagree that it was a coup, see, e.g., [Revolution of dignity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolution_of_Dignity). Also, the cited phone call, although a mark of US interference in Ukrainian internal affairs, is hardly a proof that the revolution was orchestrated by the US. This is not to disagree or agree, but the OP could benefit from a more neutral langauge.

Comment: The rather Machiavellian concept of "never letting a serious crisis go to waste" goes back at least to Machiavelli, and most likely to prehistory. The US (and others) would have been fools not to take press the Euromaidan situation to their advantage -- after it had started. This question appears to ask whether the US had a role in getting it started. Also, calling it a "coup" is how Russia sees things. Ukrainians saw it as getting rid of a Russian puppet. The question is biased.

Comment: @RogerVadim A democratically elected leader was ousted by a violent uprising. Whether you may label those incidents "the Glorious Revolution" or "the War for Liberty", it is still a coup. Don't let the present situation in Ukraine put a blind over your eyes. Yanukovich was a russian-speacking eastern ukrainian who opted for a trade agreement with Russia that was orders of magnitude more favorable to Ukraine than the one offered by the EU (see your own link for details). If the assault to the US Capitol of 2021 had succeeded, it would be still a coup, no matter how Trump supporters named it.

Comment: @Rekesoft *"The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician"* - the problem here is not what I personally believe, but the way the question is formulated, which is against the forum rules.

Comment: @RogerVadim Do you think so? There are many other questions out there about US implication on coups against Allende, Chavez or Mosaddegh. Of course, all of those are 'acknowledged' interventions - everyone knows that the US was involved. I don't see why asking if there's evidences of US involvement in this one is "discrediting" the US, specially given its proven historical record.

Comment: @Rekesoft one needs to have the *evidence* to prove that it was a *coup*. In absence of such evidence the claim that it was a coup is clearly biased. In case of Allende one actually has recorded White House conversations of trying to udnermine it, and it was indeed a coup... although, to my knowledge, there is no established evidence that US actually coordinated with Pinichet.

Comment: @RogerVadim It was a coup. By definition of *"coup"* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d%27%C3%A9tat). You need evidence to prove *US implication* on it. That's what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Rekesoft the difference between a *coup* and a *revolution* is usually that the former is by a group of people (*Typically, it is an illegal seizure of power by a political faction, rebel group, military, or a dictator.*), whereas the latter by the majority (or a significant part) of the population. FYI, I had my much more neutral post deleted a few days ago as a *pro-Russian propaganda*: [see here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6193/38304)

Comment: If using some possibly more neutral language this seems like an answerable question.  Maybe "removal from power"?  Might be good too to mention, in the question itself, because it definitely is part of the bigger picture, that Yanukovich's security forces killed about 100 protesters in the run-up to his removal.  Which alters the picture considerably from a "coup/revolution/overthrow of a nice and benevolent elected leader" which kinda gets implied here.  I'd vote to reopen given a more transparent phrasing, because this seems an important thing to know.

Comment: and mentioning the specifics of that leaked phone call, without bothering with mentioning any of the surrounding events, certainly makes it look like a pushy leading question, as it is currently phrased.  which, again, can be corrected easily enough.

Comment: I've made an edit which makes the language more neutral.  It also removes the word "coup," because as many comments have suggest, the term does apply to the events of the day.

Comment: The term "contributed" is rather broad. In an alternative universe where the US didn't exist, would it have happened? Quite likely not. "backed" is also ambiguous, as simply wishing for something to succeed can be referred to as "backing" it.

Comment: @Rekesoft "A democratically elected leader was ousted by a violent uprising."
There were protests. There was violence between protesters and the government. There are disputes as to to what extent each side is responsible for the violence. The presidents then fled the country, which was declared an abdication. One could argue that the flight was cause by fears for his safety due to the violence, but the violence did not directly cause it.

Comment: "it is still a coup." Wikipedia says that "Typically, it [a coup] is an illegal seizure of power by a political faction, rebel group, military, or a dictator." Illegality is presented as a typical attribute, not a definitional one.  "trade agreement with Russia that was orders of magnitude more favorable to Ukraine" Cite? than the one offered by the EU (see your own link for details).

Answer (score 16):

### *Interfere* is a quite remarkable word ...

The meaning ranges from *meddling* in the affairs of other people, to *acting against* other things. Some meanings have sinister overtones, some less so.

The West, including the US, is influencing governments and civil society all over the world. Some of this is the work of Western civil society, some is the work of Western corporations, some is the work of government, and some falls in between. Overt government-sponsored interference includes agencies like the [Voice of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_America), the [Instituto Cervantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_Cervantes), or the [Konrad Adenauer Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Adenauer_Foundation). And the West is not alone in this. China has the [Confucius Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius_Institute) and Russia has the [Rossotrudnichestvo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Agency_for_the_Commonwealth_of_Independent_States_Affairs,_Compatriots_Living_Abroad,_and_International_Humanitarian_Cooperation). When agencies like that *influence* the political developments in a country, those who are against it mutter about *foreign control.* Both [Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_foreign_agent_law) and the [United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Agents_Registration_Act) have a foreign agents restrictions to hinder these activities.

There can be no doubt that Western societies **approved** of parts of the [Euromaidan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euromaidan) movement, and provided moral, intellectual, and even financial support. That's different from **causing or controlling** it.

### *Coup* is another remarkable word ...

*Coup* stands for coup d'etat, which is generally understood as the violent overthrow of a government by a **small, inside group.** Opposed to that is *revolution,* the violent overthrow of a government by a **large part** of the population. And *rebellion*, which has connotations of separatism. From **outside**, one would speak of a *coup de main*, but that sort of event is not generally abbreviated as just a *coup*.

So a pat reply would be that the US did not *interfere* in the 2014 *coup* because there was no *coup,* there was a *revolution.* Which was not directed by the West, as far as we know.

Comment: The answer could be improved by removal of the last paragraph. The definition of "coup" in encyclopedia britannica mentions "small group"; wikipedia and others do not. Neither mentions how many is "small" versus "big". Collins mentions "small group", but then compares coups and revolutions saying that "coups last days, revolutions run for years", or "revolutions produce profound societal change; coups produce changes in political leadership and often little else", which would make the Euromaidan much more coup than revolution.

Comment: @Rekesoft, the comments on the question show a certain controversy about the *loaded words* it uses. I wanted to dissect two of those words. I checked coup d'etat in M-W, which also says 'small.'

Comment: In many ways, 2014 events were initiated and mediated by Ukrainian parliament, this is an argument in favor of calling it a *coup*.

Comment: well explained, upvote from me. However, reading the extensive comments on my question calling for neutral language I have tried to edit the question accordingly which might, unfortunately, make your answer a bit redundant(still encourage you to keep it up here!)

Comment: A revolution can be non-violent (not sure if a coup can be).

Comment: @gerrit, a revolution without even the *threat* of violence is indistinguishable from a government-sponsored reform, I'd say. But yes, violence is only the main connotation, not the only one.

Answer (score 11):

*(Disclaimer: I'm worried that this answer will look biased. It is, because the question asks for evidence of US interference. Of course Russia has interfered in Ukraine as well, and I consider Putin's actions to be worse than those of the US. But I'm limiting this post to neutral sources that report on US interference.)*

There are independent reports that the US has been involved in government changes in Ukraine and Georgia. The story [dates back to 2004](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/nov/26/ukraine.usa).
The current events also closely mirror [what was reported back in 2014](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/apr/30/russia-ukraine-war-kiev-conflict).

There is evidence that Joe Biden has been diplomatically involved in Ukraine from [at least as far back as 2014](https://www.denverpost.com/2014/02/24/joe-biden-is-at-the-center-of-us-diplomacy-in-ukraine/). The leak that probably prompts these questions is [also from 2014](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-ukraine-tape-idUSBREA1601G20140207).

But it doesn't come to the point of orchestrating a coup. The closest to a scientific source I've found so far is this [conference paper from 2014](https://www.drake.edu/media/departmentsoffices/international/nelson/INTERATIONAL%20ACTORS%20IN%20UKRAINE%E2%80%99S%20REVOLUTION.pdf). It shows that there was significant EU and US involvement in Ukraine, but that involvement supported an already existing movement rather than outright create it.

Overall, from publicly available evidence, **it does not appear that 2014's Maidan was directly a US-organized coup**. It was supported by prior US involvement and perhaps interference, but not directed by the US.

There are [links between the revolution and US officials](https://moderndiplomacy.eu/2018/06/04/how-and-why-the-u-s-government-perpetrated-the-2014-coup-in-ukraine/) (warning: think tank). The 2000-2014 US policy in Ukraine has certainly been a factor. But overall, the US has displayed a preference for democratic or semi-democratic means. The resulting situation appears to be the combined result of prolonged interference by two powerful actors, and in some part the population's own development, rather than something directly orchestrated by someone specific.

Comment: I'm not DV this (yet) because I haven't consulted the sources linked, but paras 2-4 are rather weak assertions / repetitions of the kind "yes, yes, there was, Biden did it" with little in the way of specifics of what the interference consisted of.

Comment: @Fizz I wouldn't say "Biden did it". There's clearly evidence that Biden was involved there - to some extent - just not that him or anyone else specifically orchestrated it.

Comment: Frankly the Guardian article is pretty ridiculous "US pollsters and professional consultants are hired to organise focus groups and use psephological data to plot strategy." But so did Yanukovych; his campaign was also run by Americans.

Comment: @Fizz The whole thing is a mess... Multiple foreign actors, limited transparency, conflicting reports. I'm trying my best to get a less-biased picture.

Comment: @Fizz "run by Americans" doesn't mean a whole lot if those Americans were not paid by the US government, or, at least, by an American political party.  If these were private individuals, working for hire, that's par for the course.  Bush (senior's) campaign printed some campaign paraphernalia in Mexico.  That was a form of hiring foreigners to work on the campaign. It was embarrassing, but not illegal.